# Prevent Gitlab adding -NoProfile to PowerShell when starting a docker container

Tags: powershell, docker, xamarin, msbuild, gitlab

**1. How can I prevent Gitlab from adding -NoProfile when creating the docker container?**

**2. What's the difference between using powershell with -NoProfile and without it?**

**3. Is there any way if I run powershell -NoProfile to somehow load/run the default profile and to revert the effect of setting -NoProfile flag?**

And now the story behind these questions:

MSBuild (Visual Studio build tool command) fails to build Xamarin app when used in docker container started by Gitlab with Powershell -NoProfile.

I created a docker image for CI purspose and everything is working properly if I run the container manually, but when it is run during Gitlab runner job, it fails (more exactly msbuild /t:SignAndroidPackage fails, because of some file does not gets generated). I inspected this (put a sleep of 1 hour in gitlab-ci.yml and attached to the container on the runner machine) and found out that Gitlab starts the container with PowerShell -NoProfile...I tried that manually(start the container with -NoProfile) and I reproduced the issue.

the error is:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\builds\gitlab\HMI.Framework\KDI\sub\HostApplicationToolkit\sub\KBle\KBle\sub\XamarinBluetooth\Source\Plugin.BLE.Android\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs'
```

Here the Resource.Designer.cs is missing (and it should be auto-generated during the build process)

This is the dockerFile:

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core image with .NET Framework 4.8.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

ENV VS_STUDIO_INSTALL_LINK=https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/befdb1f9-8676-4693-b031-65ee44835915/c541feeaa77b97681f7693fc5bed2ff82b331b168c678af1a95bdb1138a99802/vs_Community.exe
ENV VS_INSTALLER_PATH=C:\TEMP\vs2019.exe
ENV ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK=29 

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

ADD $VS_STUDIO_INSTALL_LINK $VS_INSTALLER_PATH
RUN %VS_INSTALLER_PATH% --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --includeRecommended --includeOptional`
   --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat `
   --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.XamarinBuildTools `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0 
RUN del %VS_INSTALLER_PATH%
 
# set some util paths
RUN setx JAVA_HOME "c:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\"
RUN setx path "%path%;c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"

# update android SDK with API 29
RUN echo y| sdkmanager "platforms;android-%ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK%"

#ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

This is the gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: visualstudio2019-xamarin-ci:1.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

stages:
  - build
  - test
  
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: 'recursive'


build_kdi:
   stage: build
   only:
    - CI_CD
   tags:
    - docker-windows
   script:
    - '& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" ./src/KDI/KDI.sln /t:Restore /p:AndroidBuildApplicationPackage=true /p:Configuration=Release'
    - '& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Release /t:SignAndroidPackage /property:SolutionDir="C:\builds\gitlab\HMI.Framework\KDI\src\KDI\" /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore="C:\builds\gitlab\HMI.Framework\KDI\distribution\Android\KrohneAndroidKeystore.keystore" .\src\KDI\KDI\KDI.Android\KDI.Android.csproj'

    
run_bb_tests:
   stage: test
   only:
    - CI_CD
   tags:
    - docker-windows
   script:
    - docker-ci/install_and_run_bb_tests.bat "phone_ip" "5555" arg1 arg2 || true
    - adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myApp/files/Exports/BBT_Exports/BBTests_CI C:\test_results
   artifacts:
    paths:
     - c:\test_results\BBTests_CI #expire in 1 month by default
```

If I start this image using : *docker run -it myImage powershell* everything works well, but if I run it *docker run -it myImage powershell -NoProfile*, msbuild fails at some step in building the xamarin app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I prevent Gitlab from adding -NoProfile when creating the docker container?

Apparently you can't...yet [but there is a feature request in place](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4315)

> 2. What's the difference between using powershell with -NoProfile and without it?

A PowerShell profile is just a file that contains things, like custom functions, for a specific user. For instance, if I were to have `Function Banana(){Write-Host "Awesome"}` in my PowerShell profile e.g $Home[My ]Documents\PowerShell\Profile.ps1. Whenever I open up PowerShell, it loads that function automatically. So I can open PowerShell, type `banana` and have the string `Awesome` written to stdout. If I were to start powershell with -NoProfile, and enter `banana`, I'd get `CommandNotFoundException`.
[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7)

> 3. Is there any way if I run powershell -NoProfile to somehow load/run the default profile and to revert the effect of setting -NoProfile flag?

Maybe. And I only say maybe because I haven't personally tested it, but in theory it should work. If the profile is in the container, all you have to do is dot source it.

```
. "C:\path\to\powershell\profile.ps1"
```

dot sourcing the .ps1 file will run anything within it, inside the current scope, which includes loading functions, if any are present.
[dot source docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)

My expertise on Gitlab is limited, but due to my overall experience with Windows containers, PowerShell, as well as the nature of PowerShell profiles, I have doubts that the profiling is the root cause of this issue, but I don't have enough information/evidence to definitively say. Hope this helps in some way!

Comment: Thanks, it seems you are right about the -NoProfile not being the "guilty" one, I've found that when I run the CI without docker, but with powershell as docker executor (powershell is started by Gitlab the same way as it was started in the docker container, with -NoProfile) the build just works, so -NoProfile is not the cause. Something is happening in the docker continaer, there the -NoProfile makes the difference, but don't know why and I will leave the docker for now and stick with the powershell from the CI machine as the gitlab executor...