# Problem compiling source code with french accents using msbuild in a docker with gitlab-runner

Tags: .net, docker, encoding, msbuild, gitlab-ci-runner

#### gitlab-runner seems to force the `buildtools` docker image to run in a particular encoding, and is what I don't understand, and is why I'm asking you your lights!

We are experiencing an encoding problem when compiling projects with a gitlab-runner installed on a Windows 10 machine with Docker and an image built with the following Dockerfile :

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

WORKDIR C:\
ENV UseEnv=true

SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe vs_buildtools.exe 
RUN `
    (start /w vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
        --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) `
    `
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_buildtools.exe

# Prepare folder for COPY
RUN mkdir C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell
# Switch Codepage to UTF-8
COPY .\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install Chocolatey
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));

# Install SDKs for .NET 6 and .NET 7 with some tools and choco-cleaner
RUN choco install --no-progress -y choco-cleaner grep awk micro zip unzip wget curl netfx-4.8-devpack dotnet-6.0-sdk dotnet-7.0-sdk; choco-cleaner

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

With `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`:

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

Building the Docker image this way:

```bash
docker build -t buildtools -m 2G .
```

And running it the following way:

```bash
docker run --name VS2022 -it buildtools
```

Gives us the following environment:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.7.0
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
PS C:\> $OutputEncoding


BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001
```

Also, here the gitlab-runner config.toml:

```ini
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "VS2022 msbuild"
  url = "http://gitlab.domain.com/"
  id = 13
  token = "glrt-8******************5"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-08-25T19:18:01Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker-windows"
  shell = "powershell"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "buildtools"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["c:\\cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
```

Everything seems in place but when the gitlab-runner tries to execute the build task, here is what we are facing:

```
C:\...\Controllers\ContactViewController.cs(125,45): error CS1056: Unexpected character '�'
```

This means 2 things:

- The character, which is `é`, is not recognized, which also means the msbuild command is not executed in UTF8 environment
- gitlab-runner seems to force the `buildtools` docker image to run in a particular encoding, and is what I don't understand, and is why I'm asking you your lights!

Here is the pipeline definition `.gitlab-ci.yml`, where we've also tried to add `chcp 65001` as 1st script item, but changed nothing:

```yaml
variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH: '*/*/'

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json'
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*'
    - '$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'

before_script:
  - nuget restore -NonInteractive -PackagesDirectory $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY "Some Solution.sln"

stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build

build-job:       # This job runs in the build stage, which runs first.
  tags:
    - dotnet-fw-4.8
    - devexpress
  stage: build
  script:
    - chcp 65001
    - msbuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64" /p:OutputPath="c:/build/release/" "Some Solution.sln"
```

Comment: tried to reolace `chcp 65001` with manual call to powershell profile with no success (since it appears gitlan-runner docker calls build docker with `-NoProfile`).

Comment: Also follow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71316167/gitlab-ci-docker-in-docker-with-dotnet-testcontainers?rq=2

Comment: And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168705/prevent-gitlab-adding-noprofile-to-powershell-when-starting-a-docker-container?rq=2